# Oxygen Builder Gallery: Get a custom-field-gallery from another post

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, image-gallery, oxygenbuilder

I use oxygen builder to create a page. The page should contain a oxygen-builder-gallery. That gallery should show the images of an custom advanced-image-field created with Meta Box.
BUT: That custom filed belongs to antother post and not to the page that contains the gallery.
Is there a way to achieve that?

I don't have any solid approaches.
Just a loose idea: I assume that the oxygen builder gallery calls a function to get the images that should be shown. If there is a way to manipulate that function in a way that it returns the gallery from that other post...